# Boot parameters in qemu

Tags: c, linux-kernel, boot, qemu

I'm new at kernel programming and trying to do a "Hello World" example. I added the following code to init/main.c in start_kernel()

```
#ifdef HELLO
   printk("Hello World");
#endif
```

Now to my question. How do i define HELLO in the boot parameters using qemu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `HELLO` at compile time, (either with `-DHELLO` as a compiler flag or `#define HELLO` somewhere), otherwise the compiler never even sees the `printk` call and no code for it gets emitted.

You can't make the C compiler get re-run at early stage boot time based on the boot parameters, which is what you'd need to do to change `HELLO` there.

The kernel is no different than any other C program in this respect - preprocessor directives are handled really early on in compilation.

You can setup parameters with [this helper macro](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.7/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L106) that are a regular variable that can be set a boot and tested at runtime (not compile time) with a plain old `if` statement.

Comment: My question is if there are any way to define HELLO after the code are compiled by using a boot parameter

Comment: @nist - The kernel isn't special, the pre-processor still happens really early in compilation just like any other C program. You can write normal `if` statements in the kernel just like you can in any other C program though if you want instead of `#ifdef`

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I use if statements how could i make my kernel behave diffrently with diffrent bootparameters and how do I add my own boot parameter?

Comment: @nist - http://www.de-brauwer.be/wiki/wikka.php?wakka=HelloParam shows an example of the usual way. I think if you want to do it that early in boot up you'd need to use [__setup](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/include/linux/init.h#L231) though.